# JFreeChart: remove gridlines on CombinedDomainXYPlot with PeriodAxis

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

**Context:** Java swing application generating a chart using JFreeChart. The chart is a `CombinedDomainXYPlot` (using `XYBarRenderer`) that on the X-axis has a timeline based on `PeriodAxis`.

**Problem:** I can't remove the vertical gridlines (not the tickmarks related to the time periods) that separate days.
What I tried is: `combinedPlot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false)` which doesn't work (see image below).

[image]

Any hint would be more than welcome!

Thx,
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

After some additional research I found the mistake: for `CombinedDomainXYPlot` the `setDomainGridlinesVisible(false)` needs to be called on the subplots:

```
List<XYPlot> subplots = (List<XYPlot>) combinedPlots.getSubplots();
for (XYPlot p:subplots) p.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
```